# C++ WinInet only making 1 request

Tags: php, c++, apache, wininet

I'm having trouble using `WinInet` locally. I have a local Apache webserver (xampp) which is running nicely, the problem is that when I try to make a GET request to a PHP script, it seems to be only doing it once. The PHP script simply outputs a random number, and I see the same number 3 times (the script isn't at fault). I've also checked the Apache access log and it only shows up once. The odd thing is that when NOT using it locally, the loop works perfectly and it does send out multiple requests (Wireshark shows this too).

Here is the code, simplified and still giving problems:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <WinInet.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#pragma comment(lib, "wininet.lib")

void req()
{
    HINTERNET hInternet = InternetOpenW(L"useragent", INTERNET_OPEN_TYPE_DIRECT, NULL, NULL, 0);

    HINTERNET hConnect = InternetConnectW(hInternet, L"127.0.0.1", 80, NULL, NULL, INTERNET_SERVICE_HTTP, 0, NULL);

    HINTERNET hRequest = HttpOpenRequestW(hConnect, L"GET", L"test/test.php", NULL, NULL, NULL, 0, 0);

    BOOL bRequestSent = HttpSendRequestW(hRequest, NULL, 0, NULL, 0);       

    std::string strResponse;
    const int nBuffSize = 1024;
    char buff[nBuffSize];

    BOOL bKeepReading = true;
    DWORD dwBytesRead = -1;

    while (bKeepReading && dwBytesRead != 0)
    {
        bKeepReading = InternetReadFile(hRequest, buff, nBuffSize, &dwBytesRead);
        strResponse.append(buff, dwBytesRead);
    }

    std::cout << strResponse << std::endl;

    InternetCloseHandle(hRequest);  
    InternetCloseHandle(hConnect);
    InternetCloseHandle(hInternet);
}

int main()
{
    for (int x = 0;x < 3; x++) // 3 times
    {
        req();
        Sleep(2000);
    }

    system("PAUSE");
}
```

I can't seem to figure this out...

Answer (score 1):

I am unable to reproduce your observation if I query the for example `www.google.com`.

I think that your program simply continues reading the response with `InternetReadFile` but the other process on your machine has not yet completed the request. I suggest to wait for the request to complete using [`WinHttpReceiveResponse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384105%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) before reading the response contents.

Some more things concerning your implementation:

- You do not need to call `InternetOpen(..)` for each new request. Is is sufficient to do this once and to store the returned handle until your application terminates.
- It is very important to check for errors! Your function simply relies on all calls to succeed which obviously doesn't seem to be the case due to your question...